# Spock: check the query parameter count in URI

Tags: groovy, spock

I have just started with spock. I have one functionality. where the java function makes an http call. As per functionality, the URI used in http call, must contain "loc" parameter and it should be only once.

I am writing Spock test case. I have written below snippet.

```
def "prepareURI" () {

    given: "Search Object"
        URI uri = new URI();
    when:
        uri = handler.prepareURI( properties) // it will return URI like http://example.com?query=abc&loc=US
    then:
        with(uri)
        {
            def map = uri.getQuery().split('&').inject([:]) {map, kv-> def (key, value) = kv.split('=').toList(); map[key] = value != null ? URLDecoder.decode(value) : null; map }

            assert map.loc != null
        }
}
```

From above snippet, my 2 tests got passed like

- It should be exists
- It should not be null

I want to check the count of "loc" query parameter. It should be passed exactly once. With map as above, If I pass "loc" parameter twice, map overrides the old value with 2nd one.

Does any one knows, how to access the query parameters as list, and in list I want to search the count of Strings which starts with "loc"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an example would be the best start:

```
def uri    = new URI('http://example.com?query=abc&loc=US')
def parsed = uri.query.tokenize('&').collect { it.tokenize('=') }

println "parsed to list: $parsed"
println "count of 'loc' params:            " + parsed.count { it.first() == 'loc' }
println "count of 'bob' params:            " + parsed.count { it.first() == 'bob' }
println "count of params with value 'abc': " + parsed.count { it.last()  == 'abc' }
```

prints:

```
$ groovy test.groovy 
parsed to list: [[query, abc], [loc, US]]
count of 'loc' params:            1
count of 'bob' params:            0
count of params with value 'abc': 1
```

the problem, as you correctly noted, is that you can not put your params into a map if your intent is to count the number of params with a certain name.

In the above, we parse the params in to a list of lists where the inner lists are key, value pairs. This way we can call `it.first()` to get the param names and `it.last()` to get the param values. The groovy `List.count { }` method lets us count the occurences of a certain item in the list of params.

As for your code, there is no need to call `new URI()` at the beginning of your test as you set the value anyway a few lines down.

Also the `with(uri)` call is unnecessary as you don't use any of the uri methods without prefixing them with `uri.` anyway. I.e. you can either write:

```
def uri    = new URI('http://example.com?query=abc&loc=US')
def parsed = uri.query.tokenize('&').collect { it.tokenize('=') }
```

or:

```
def uri = new URI('http://example.com?query=abc&loc=US')
uri.with { 
  def parsed = query.tokenize('&').collect { it.tokenize('=') }
}
```

(note that we are using `query` directly in the second example)

but there is not much point in using with if you are still prefixing with `uri.`.

The resulting test case might look something like:

```
def "prepareURI"() {
    given: "Search Object"
        def uri = handler.prepareURI( properties) // it will return URI like http://example.com?query=abc&loc=US

    when:
        def parsed = query.tokenize('&').collect { it.tokenize('=') }

    then:
        assert parsed.count { it.first() == 'loc' } == 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea. by the way the URI api, never allows duplicate query parameters, it takes the latest query parameters if we try to put the same query parameter.